# output Array[Pair[X,Y]] to file inside a WDL task

Tags: wdl

I have a table containing different metadata information about a set of samples as an Array[Object] and I need to extract a couple of columns from this table and output those two columns into a file that will be read and used by the task. I wanted to know whether I can do this within a task rather than within a workflow, that is, without using the scatter construct which is not allowed inside a task.

If I zip two arrays I obtain an Array[Pair[String,String]] variable.

Now if I want to output to file an Array[Array[String]] I can use write_tsv(), if I want to output to file a Map[String,String] I can use write_map().

But WDL does not let me coerce Array[Pair[String,String]] to either Array[Array[String]] nor Map[String,String] (though I can coerce Map[String,String] to Array[Pair[String,String]]), so neither option is available.

Is there a solution to this that does not involve the scatter construct?

Comment: Hi @freeseek, could you please explain the biological relevance behind you informatics WDL question? Are you using BioWDL?

Answer (score 0):

`write_json()` is supposed to provide the general way to serialize any data structure for processing/manipulation in the task command script (perhaps leveraging [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)). Unfortunately, last I heard, [Cromwell's implementation doesn't work on some useful cases](https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/labels/Read%2Fwrite%20JSON%20array%20bug) right now. (Possibly out of date; I haven't tried lately)

Comment: Just learned this yesterday: in the development version you could try to use `as_map()` and then `write_map()`. However, you have to assume that all the left element in the `Array[Pair[String,String]]` array are unique or `as_map()` will fail.